# Два запроса на сервер redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

У меня есть необходимость сделать последовательно два запроса на сервер:
getAllPersons и затем getPersonsForSelect.

Данные запросы должны уходить на сервер при загрузке приложения и я делаю их используя useEffect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllPersons(mainPersonId))
    dispatch(getPersonsForSelect(processName))
  },[])

  const allbossPerson = useSelector(store => { return store.persons.allbossPerson })
  const personsForSelect = useSelector(store => { return store.persons.personsForSelect })
```

Проблема в том, что используя console.log() я получаю по два обращения на сервер, т.е. всего 4:

```
import {
    GET_ALL_PERSONS,
    GET_PERSONS_FOR_SELECT
} from "../types/person"

const initialState = {
    allbossPerson: [],
    personsForSelect: []
}

export const persons = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_ALL_PERSONS:
            console.log('GET_ALL_PERSONS')
            const allPersons = action.allPersons.slice();
            return {
                ...state,
                allbossPerson: allPersons
            }
        case GET_PERSONS_FOR_SELECT:
            console.log('GET_PERSONS_FOR_SELECT')
            const personsForSelect = action.personsForSelect.slice();
            return {
                ...state,
                personsForSelect: personsForSelect
            }
            default:
                return state
    }
}
```

Т.е. в консоли у меня вот такая картина:

```
GET_PERSONS_FOR_SELECT
2personReducer.js:14 GET_ALL_PERSONS
personReducer.js:21 GET_PERSONS_FOR_SELECT
```

Что я делаю не так? Почему вызоываются они по 2 раза?

Comment: Вероятно, это стандартное поведение react, при котором некоторые компоненты рендерятся дважды. Считается, что так больше шансов отловить все ошибки. Чтобы проверить, действительно ли это так, попробуйте либо забилдить проект (запустить yarn build или npm run build) либо закомментируйте useStrict в файле App.js

Comment: так ведь обращение на сервер дважды

Comment: @elari все правильно, при рендере компонента происходит обращение на сервер и его результат выводится в консоль. После этого, компонент рендерится снова, то есть useEffect срабатывает повторно, а потому и обращение к серверу происходит еще раз

Comment: Простите, возможно, за глупый вопрос. Надо ли мне убрать  
    dispatch(getAllPersons(mainPersonId))
    dispatch(getPersonsForSelect(processName))  
из useEffect? Т.е. это нормальная практика и при рендере компонента эти запросы будут отправляться единожды?

Comment: сейчас напишу подробно в ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Двойной рендер компонента - стандартное явление для React. Это связано с тем, что при разработке это может помочь найти некоторые ошибки. В данный момент ваш код работает по такой схеме: 
**Отрисовать компонент -> сделать 2 запроса -> повторно отрисовать компонент -> повторно сделать 2 запроса** 
Такое поведение явно не играет нам на руку, так что есть несколько способов его избежать.
1 способ - отключить строгий режим. Для этого, нужно открыть файл index.js, который выглядит примерно так (у вас может отличаться, я взял из своего проекта):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/reducers/rootReducer';

const app = <Provider store={store}>
              <BrowserRouter>
                <React.StrictMode>   // строгий режим
                  <App />
                </React.StrictMode>
              </BrowserRouter>
            </Provider>
            
ReactDOM.render(
  app, document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Все, что нужно сделать - закомментировать строчки <React.StrictMode> (или вообще их удалить), после чего строгий режим будет отключен. То есть, файл должен выглядеть так:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/reducers/rootReducer';

const app = <Provider store={store}>
              <BrowserRouter>
                {/* <React.StrictMode> */}
                  <App />
                {/* </React.StrictMode> */}
              </BrowserRouter>
            </Provider>
            
ReactDOM.render(
  app, document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Другой вариант, который не совсем решит проблему, но позволит убедиться, что все работает корректно - забилдить проект. Билд - финальная сборка проекта, то есть это даст вам возможность посмотреть на проект в том виде, в котором он будет размещен в интернете. Для этого, остановите localhost, а затем запустите снова командой **npm run build** или **yarn build**. Когда мы билдим проект, строгий режим отключается автоматически, что дает нам возможность увидеть, какое количество рендеров было произведено

Comment: Если остались вопросы, не стесняйтесь задавать